# Bridge on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, ethernet

I found on the page[link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html).

instructions to setup a bridge between eth0 and wlan0. 
In particular, my system should connect to the SSID (ASUS_HOME) of my wifi modem router located at `192.168.1.1` and give connectivity to my Ethernet device connected on the eth0. 
I installed bridge-utils, I'm able to setup a bridge br0 between eth0 and wlan0, but not able to connect wlan0 to my ssid.
Please, could you suggest me how to modify my `/etc/network/interfaces` to work with a above described bridge.
Thanks

Note:
the current  working (without bridge) configuration for `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

with /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
    ssid="ASUS_HOME"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=WPA RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    psk=a26fb86c858bfa33d3ae4e774a6e4c01d53915c7ee83fe92b44e1fc8903b85ab
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install bridge utilities if not installed with

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
brctl show
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig br0 up
iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
brctl addif br0 wlan0
brctl addif br0 eth0
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

For more information please follow below two links.

[importgeek.wordpress.com](http://importgeek.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/bridge-traffic-between-two-network-interfaces-in-gnulinux/)

[serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/152363/bridging-wlan0-to-eth0)

Comment: The command suggested are not usefull: iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on gives command failed: No such device (-19)
After brctl addif br0 wlan0 i loose wlan connectivity

Comment: No such device ? whats your Wifi Interface name ?

Comment: It's an usb device located on wlan0:

Comment: lsusb: ...Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. ...
It's an usb device located on wlan0: Realtek RTL8723AU.

Comment: nmcli device
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
wlan0      802-11-wireless   connected

Comment: is there a way modifying /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces ?