# Make AP using Jetson TK1 board and wifi dongle LB-LINK 802.11n

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm using an NVIDIA Jetson TK1 board connected with LAN cable. My PC is running Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to make Ubuntu an Access Point. To allow another computer to access this AP, I bought a WiFi dongle, LB-LINK 802.11n.

But I don't know how to use this...

If the WiFi dongle is connected to the Jetson board, I thought I would be able to select this dongle in the board.

[image]

As you can see, However, I can't select it.

I entered the command `iwconfig`.

It shows wlan0 isn't running.

It is the result of 'lsusb'

[image]

**Chipset: Realtek RTL8188CUS**

I want to make a AP by using this Jetson TK1 board and wifi dongle.
What should I do?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded-computing

Comment: @MichaelBay relevance to the question being asked?  Or are you just providing this as a "For more information on the platform" thing?

Comment: @ThomasWard et al Yes, and also just in case it isn't Ubuntu. Not really clear in 2 out of 3 of this questions. If it's running Ubuntu it should be like any other, what is there to troubleshoot is the WiFi (after assuring it can work in an hub).

Comment: @MichaelBay ah, how about you ask the user that, rather than just post a link to the referenced device?  (Unclear comments are ***equally*** as bad as unclear questions)

Comment: @DaehyunPark Can you please post the results of `lsusb`?

Comment: @MichaelBay I edited.

Comment: Please don' t post results as a screenshoot. Copy in terminal by selecting the full text and righ-click > copy or CTRL+SHIFT+C. I edited again to include your latest screenshot and highlight the hardware that matters for troubleshoot.

Comment: Now, where Ubuntu is running is irrelevant. Adding the dev board is potentially misleading and just noise. Your issue is no different than thousands others. An ARM CPU like yours may limit the software that can be installed but everything else should be exactly the same, including drivers.

Comment: First you need to have a working WiFi. Any current release, including 16.04.2, should support RTL8188CUS; 14.04 probably not. Then, after having the WiFi working correctly. you want this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/566378/bridge-on-ubuntu-14-04 (same for newer releases).